# Java character array prints the index

Tags: java, arrays

`char_array[]` is "x, a, x, c, x, b, x, a, x, x ,b ,x ,x, x, x"

`key_array[]` is "a, b, c"

expected return array: "1, 5, 3"

The goal is to print the index of the `char_array` that matches with `key_array`. For example, in this case the program has to print "1, 5, 3". It only counts the first index it matches.

Another example would be that

`char_array[]` is "q, h, e, h, w, e, r, t, l, y, l, l, o"

`key_array[]` is "h, e, l, l, o"

expected return array: "1, 2, 8, 10, 12"

What I have tried so far is

```
int index = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < key_array.length; i++)
{
    isFound = false;
    for(int k = index + 1; k < char_array.length && isFound == false; k++) 
    {
        if(char_array[i] == key_array[k])
        {
            index = k;
            num[j] = index;
            isFound = true;
        }
    }
}
```

This way, my second example which deals with "hello" works but my first example which deals with "abc" doesn't work.

I started my `k` with `index+1`, but I guess I will have to change this from 0 to `char_array.length`..

Can someone help me with this logic please

Comment: Hint: loop over the "key" array, and for each char C, loop over the other array and when you find the C print the index and `break`, then repeat

Comment: Why wouldn't the "h, e, l, l, o" version output "1, 2, 8, 8, 12"?

Comment: You need to take are of reinitializing `index` to 0

Comment: @Tibrogargan because 8 is already counted. So it shouldn't be counted again.

Comment: @user7 but when I reinitialize index to 0, it counts the index again like in hello example above, it shouldn't print 1 2 8 8 12, it should be 1 2 8 10 12

Comment: In that case you are only progressing sequentially, and there is no way to get `1,5,3` in the first case

Comment: @Eric Your snippet is wrong by the way, it should be `char_array[k] == key_array[i]`

Comment: hello, you should verify that the current valid index is not already in the result array before putting it in result then you'll have 1 2 8 10 12 and not 1 2 8 8 12.

Comment: Nice question. You were close but I think you can do this by O(n) time no need to use thouse inner loops. They are just making it complicated.

Answer (score 2):

Try this;

```
for(int i=0;i<key_array.length;i++)
{
    int pos=new String(char_array).indexOf(key_array[i]);

    char_array[pos]='0'                          //considering there is no numeric character in char_array  

    collection.push(pos);                        //collection is a java Collection framework's object
}
```

Comment: Why not? `char_array` never is updated. It's pointless to recreate the string inside the loop

Comment: @cricket_007 so he can use indexOf.  Tricky.  Too bad the output is wrong, this would be a nice solution

Comment: Also, this doesn't take into account repeating characters can't have the same number. See the "hello" example

Comment: I thought you were asking to to keep whole statement out side of the loop.

Comment: @Tibrogargan - the string should be moved to a variable outside the loop. The indexOf should stay

Comment: Moving the String creation outside the loop is really just an optimization the compiler would have done anyway.  The real problem is that the solution produces an incorrect result

Answer (score 0):

Seems to do the trick

```
static int[] foo(char[] char_array, char[] key_array) {
    // copy the original so we can modify to avoid repeats
    char[] copy = new char[char_array.length];
    System.arraycopy(char_array, 0, copy, 0, char_array.length);
    int[] result = new int[key_array.length];
    boolean found = true;
    for(int i = 0; found && i < key_array.length; i++) {
        found = false;
        for(int j = 0; j < copy.length; j++) {
            if (copy[j] == key_array[i]) {
                copy[j] = 0;
                result[i] = j;
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (found) {
        return result;
    }
    return null;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(foo("xaxcxbxaxxbxxxx".toCharArray(), "abc".toCharArray())));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(foo("qhehwertlyllo".toCharArray(), "hello".toCharArray())));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This only works for the second example, since the chars occur in order.

However you need to decide the index to start the search based on whether you've seached the string for this char before (start after the char found).

E.g.

```
for (int i = 0; i < key_array.length; i++) {
     char c = key_array[i];
     int previousIndex;

     // go back and find the last index with a matching char
     for (previousIndex = i-1; previousIndex >= 0 && key_array[previousIndex] != c; previousIndex--) {}

     if (previousIndex >= 0 && num[previousIndex] == -1) {
          // last key not found => no further matches available
          num[i] = -1;
     } else {
          // find occurence of char after last match
          num[i] = -1;
          for (int j = (previousIndex >= 0 ? num[previousIndex] + 1 : 0); j < char_array.length; j++) {
               if (char_array[j] == c) {
                    num[i] = j;
                    break;
               }
          }
     }
}
```

---

Alternatively use a `Map` to store the indices by `char` and use this to retrieve the indices efficiently:

```
// find list of indices by char
Map<Character, ?> map = IntStream.range(0, char_array.length).boxed().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> char_array[i]));

for (Map.Entry e : map.entrySet()) {
    // replace values with iterator over index lists
    e.setValue(((List)e.getValue()).iterator());
}

for (int i = 0; i < key_array.length; i++) {
    Iterator<Integer> iterator = (Iterator<Integer>) map.get(key_array[i]);
    num[i] = (iterator == null || !iterator.hasNext() ? -1 : iterator.next());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do the job ( O(n) ) :

```
char[] char_array = {'q', 'h', 'e', 'h', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'l', 'y', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
char[] key_array = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};

Map<Character, Queue<Integer>> charPossitions = new HashMap<Character, Queue<Integer>>();
for(int i = 0; i < char_array.length; i++){
    if(charPossitions.get(char_array[i]) == null){           
       Queue<Integer> possitionsQueue=new LinkedList<Integer>();
       possitionsQueue.add(i);
       charPossitions.put(char_array[i], possitionsQueue);
    }else { 
       charPossitions.get(char_array[i]).add(i);
    }                                           
}
for(char key : key_array){
    System.out.println(key + "/" + charPossitions.get(key).poll());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello this shoul do the trick!

```
public class Main
{

  private static final char[] liste1 = {'x', 'a', 'x', 'c', 'x', 'b', 'x', 'a', 'x', 'x' ,'b' ,'x' ,'x', 'x', 'x'};
  private static final char[] liste2 = {'q', 'h', 'e', 'h', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'l', 'y', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
  private static final char[] key1 = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
  private static final char[] key2 = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};


  private static void lookupIndexOfChar(char c, char[] list, List<Integer> result){
    for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
      if(list[i] == c){
        if(notInResult(i, result)){
          result.add(i);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  private static boolean notInResult(int i, List<Integer> result)
  {
    return !(result == null || result.contains(i));
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (char c : key1)
    {
      lookupIndexOfChar(c, liste1, result);
    }
    for (Integer integer : result)
    {
      System.out.print(integer);
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
    result.clear();
    for (char c : key2)
    {
      lookupIndexOfChar(c, liste2, result);
    }
    for (Integer integer : result)
    {
      System.out.print(integer);
    }
  }

}
```